# Getting Exception With DB2 Select from Table

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, db2, sqlexception

I keep getting the "java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found." when trying select from a table using DB2 on Netbeans. Here is my table creation code:

```
string="CREATE TABLE PlayerCollection "
                + "(id integer not null GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),"
                + "name varchar(20),"
                + "height varchar(20),"
                + "weight varchar(20),"
                + "position varchar(20),"
                + "team varchar(20),"
                + "PRIMARY KEY (id))";
```

And here is my code to select from the table:

```
String sql = "select name, height, weight, position, team from PlayerCollection "
                        + "where id=" + strIndex;
```

Why am I getting this exception even though "id" clearly exists in my table and how do I fix this? 
Actually it seems that my error is at this line:

```
int ind = rs.getInt("id");
```

Here `"rs"` is a result set.

Comment: Actually it seems that my error is at this line "int ind = rs.getInt("id");" Here "rs" is a result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resultset contains only the columns that you select, so you must include the column `id` in the select list:

```
String sql = "select id, name, height, weight, position, team from PlayerCollection "
           + "where id=" + strIndex;
```

or since you have the `id`'s value in the variable `strIndex` which you use in the `WHERE` clause, simply remove the line:

```
int ind = rs.getInt("id");
```

from your code, or change it to this:

```
int ind = Integer.parseInt(strIndex);
```